# Browser opens the page at the point of the Form, not at the top, even if i put an anchor to the top

Tags: html, forms, anchor

i am doing a very easy first website for a school project, using just css and html. I inserted a form in one of the pages at the bottom. 
When i open that page (either reloading, opening or clicking the link to that page from another)the browser open the correct pages but it goes straight to the bottom of the page where is the form. So I obviously would like that the browser opens the page at the top.
what am I doing wrong?

Any suggestion?
thanks :)

Comment: can you share your code please? what you're getting depends on what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your code looks like. Try to add this script to that page

```
 window.onbeforeunload = () => {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
};
```